# Block or press escape if a form shows up at any time during webscraping?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

This one has me completely stumped.

```
count = 1
while count < expected_pages:
    time.sleep(10)
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    time.sleep(5)
    element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[contains(text(), ' Show More Results')]")
    #wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[contains(text(), ' Show More Results')]")))
    actions = ActionChains(driver)
    actions.move_to_element(element).perform()
    actions.click().perform()
    count = count + 1
    print(count)
print("All Done!")
```

While the above starts looping, on the 3rd click there is a form which shows up blocking the content behind. However the `print(count)` keeps executing even though the button isn't being clicked.

The form seems to come up randomly every 2-3 clicks or after inactivity. I don't know what to look for to get an exact understanding of when it pops up.

Hitting ESC gets the form to disappear. I am trying to figure out if there is any way to constantly monitor for the form ID and if it is present to hit ESC before any other line executes? And restart where we paused?

Answer (score 0):

https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.common.alert

try putting Alert(driver).dismiss() after time.sleep(5). if you tell you something like "error: no alert on page" then put it in a try statement like so

```
count = 1
while count < expected_pages:
    time.sleep(10)
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,
        document.body.scrollHeight);")
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    time.sleep(5)
    try:
        Alert(driver).dismiss()
    except:
        pass
    actions = ActionChains(driver)
    actions.move_to_element(element).perform()
    actions.click().perform()
    count += 1
    print(count)
print("All Done!")
```

Comment: It isn't an alert. :( I can try to send an escape key using keys but how to only send it if the form is in foreground.

Comment: can i see what website you are scraping?

Comment: here is the link. (https://dir.indiamart.com/search.mp?ss=Power+Distribution+Transformers)